# How do you combine variables to form function in python?

Tags: python, excel, string, python-2.7, function

```
ypos = 1
ypos2 = ypos-1
xpos = 1
xpos2 = 2
```

Using these variables, that are changed each time the code loops, how do I get it to print the result below?

```
=B(ypos)-B(ypos2)
```

Every time the code loops the ypos increases by one and therefore the ypos2 increases by one

so as the code loops the results should be
1) B1-B0
2) B2-B1
3) B3-B2
etc.

Any help is much appreciated, and if you don't understand the question let me know, I wasn't quite sure how to explain it.(P.S. I am using python2.7)

Thanks, Anthony

Comment: Since a single line of code can print what you want, it isn't clear why you want to abstract it into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('B({})-B({})'.format(ypos, ypos2))
```

or

```
print('B(' + str(ypos) + ')-B(' + str(ypos2) + ')')
```

These should work in Python 2.7 or Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

This should be it:

```
print 'B({})-B({})'.format(ypos, ypos2)
```

For python2.7 prints are without parentheses, unlike in python3. Check this to verify [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: The parenthesis won't hurt in Python 2, as long as it is a single value that you are trying to print. Superfluous parenthesis are often added if the desire is to make code which can be used as is in either Python 2 or Python 3 (not always possible of course, but often is. Definitely the case here).

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, I didn't knew that.

Comment: Even better -- in Python 2 you can import the print function from the future. In any event, it is good that OP is aware of the differences between Python 2 and Python 3 regarding `print`, so +1.